# готовый класс Аналог Стека, Хипа, бинарного дерево?

Tags: c#, .net

ребята подскажите а нету ли готового класса Хипа и дерево? ну чтобы руками не писать код.. вот типа такого?

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Stack<int> ts = new Stack<int>();

        ts.Push(1);
        ts.Push(2);
        ts.Push(3);
        ts.Push(4);
        ts.Push(5);
        ts.Push(6);

        foreach (var item in ts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

вот такое только для Кучи и деревьев?

Comment: чет непонятно зачем оно. Хип для чего? Сортированные даные хранить? Есть всякие sorted list или sorted dictionary. Про дерево непонятно что нужно, там же разные представления дерева для разных задач есть.

Comment: ну я думал .... вот как стек структура данных, так и может и у кучи ест такая структура...  нет? :)

Comment: ну вот есть [PriorityQueue<TElement,TPriority>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-6.0) сделано как `Implements an array-backed, quaternary min-heap.`, если это то, что вам надо

Comment: ну да , вроде это, сейчас  прочу, спасибо